# How to write-protect an (internal HDD) partition with regedit.exe?

Tags: windows

I want to write-protect an (internal HDD) partition,
not with “diskpart.exe” and not with “gpedit.msc”,
but only with the registry (regedit.exe).

(OS: XP, Vista, 7 or 8)

Can you please help me ?

Thank you !…

Comment: Well ... you could use Process Monitor to work out what registry changes diskpart.exe is making, I suppose.  If the Group Policy setting you're thinking of is registry-based, that would be even easier; just look at the corresponding .admx file in C:\windows\policydefinitions.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of anybody doing this with the registry before.

Is the partition formatted with NTFS?  If so, you can just set security permissions on the volume at the root level to allow "Everyone" to Read only.

Remove all other NTFS permissions from the partition, and you should achieve the desired result.

```
Right click on the drive in "My Computer" and click Properties

Click the Security Tab

Remove all items from the list

Add "Everyone"

Press OK
```

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark it as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I already know how to write-protect An internal HDD partition using “diskpart.exe” with “gpedit.msc” and even the way you describe.

Comment: Using the registry, I also know how to write-protect USB HDD or how to hide a partition from the system. Of course, there is a way to write-protect an internal HDD partition using regedit. If you can help me, thank you very much !..